# UITableView with Xcode, Fetching CoreData Problem

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have been working for a project but stuck on how to retrieve CoreData to my Table View. This is my code:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

func loadData(){
       let requestData: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
       do {
           try
               personArr = context.fetch(requestData)
               try context.save()
          } catch {print ("Error retrieving data request \(error)")
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
   }

//  let DVC = segue.destination as! addPersonController
// numberOfRowsInSection ... cellForRowAt
// let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "personCell", for: indexPath)
// cell.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].title > let person = personArr[indexPath.row]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if(tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark)
       {tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
           personArr[indexPath.row].finish = false
           //cell.accessoryType = .checkmark //forRaw
       }
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) //not selected
        savePerson()
       // let myPerson = PersonArr[indexPath.row].name
       // performSegue(withIdentifier: "personSegue", sender: myPerson)
}
```

Here is just an example of some function that I applied. my concern is at fetching data to personArr that is not been fetching as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A closer look at the code reveals that you are reloading the table view in the `catch` scope which is almost never going to happen.

Move the line into the `do` scope and delete the pointless line to save the context

```
func loadData(){
   let requestData: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
   do {
       personArr = try context.fetch(requestData)
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   } catch {
       print ("Error retrieving data request \(error)")
   }
}
```